# HighCharts Wind Rose Chart "polar: true" not working

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to display a wind rose chart for my wind speed values. But yet, i was unable to convert it into a polar charts.

I am using **Angular 12** and had installed **angular-highcharts** and **highcharts** into my Angular project.

Component.ts

```
this.windchart = new HighChart.Chart({

      series: [
        {
          type: undefined,
          name: '<1 m/s',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 8, 4, 0, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1]
        },
        {
          type: undefined,
          name: '1-3 m/s',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1]
        },
        {
          type: undefined,
          name: '3-5 m/s',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
        },
        {
          type: undefined,
          name: '>5 m/s',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
      },

      title: {
        text: this.location,
        align: 'center'
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Test Graph',
        align: 'center'
      },

      pane: {
        size: '85%'
      },

      legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        layout: 'vertical'
      },

      xAxis: {
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        categories: ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']
      },

      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        showLastLabel: true,
        title: {
          text: 'Frequency (%)'
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function () {
            return this.value + '%';
          }
        },
        reversedStacks: false
      },

      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          shadow: false,
          // groupPadding: 0,
          pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
      }
    });
```

Component.html

```
<div [chart]="windchart" id="container"></div>
```

The chart appears as a column but did not change it into a polar chart.

[image: Chart output]

I was referring to highcharts demo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose

The only difference is probably the demos are using **script** tag while i am implementing Highcharts through **npm** package. Is there anything i am missing out or any error made by me?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] on stackblitz ?

Comment: I pasted your config object into the windrose fiddle from the demo and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4deLn87a/ weird

Comment: @temp_user i tried to import the package i used (angular-highcharts) but it had some error in the stackblitz so i unable to produce it for you. so sorry.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah thats why im so confused right now haha. The only possibility that i can think of is the javascript files. As you are using <script> at html page while i would prefer to use their angular packages which is angular-highcharts in this case. I not sure whether should i stick to using <script> tag or continue to find solution through their angular packages.

Comment: Guys, after numerous times of trying and searching for answers, i found this stackblitz demo code which is very useful for me and it solves my problems [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-highcharts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) . The problem is probably i used the wrong package. It should be **highcharts** instead of **angular-highcharts** for the polar:true to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this at top of the components fix the issue. It maybe not correct way, But working workaround for now.

```
require('highcharts/modules/data')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/windbarb')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
```